# Python: dataframe.get() with multi-index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` structured as follows:

```
  from       rate   to
0  CHF   1.000000  CHF
1  CHF  19.673256  MXN
2  CHF   0.000000  ZAR
3  CHF   0.000775  XAU
4  CHF  32.961405  THB
```

and I've re-indexed it to be as follows:

```
               rate
from to            
CHF  CHF   1.000000
     MXN  19.675255
     ZAR   0.000000
     XAU   0.000775
     THB  32.961068
...
```

using `df = df.set_index(['from','to'],drop=True, append=False)`.

I want to simply call `get` on the dataframe using a pair of indices. For example, I would expect `df[['CHF','MXN']]` to return `19.675255` but instead an error is raised stating `"['CHF' 'MXN'] not in index"`.

It seems like this should be very straightforward -- what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**
*`pd.IndexSlice`*

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
```

```
df.loc[idx['CHF', 'MXN']]

rate    19.673256
Name: (CHF, MXN), dtype: float64
```

If you want the result as a scalar, call `.item` -

```
df.loc[idx['CHF', 'MXN']].item()
19.673256
```

---

**Option 2**
*`xs`*

```
df.xs(['CHF', 'MXN'])

rate    19.673256
Name: (CHF, MXN), dtype: float64
```

Comment: Awesome thank you. This works. Off-hand, do you know which option should run fastest, or are they the same?

Comment: @Blake You're operating on an index, so both methods would probably be equally fast. It would depend on the individual overhead each function entails. My guess is `loc` would be slightly faster.

Comment: Let me asking a question :-)

Comment: @Wen I have one for you to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48122394/pandas-python-how-to-switch-index-columns-in-dataframe-while-retaining-df-struct/48122468#48122468

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ added an answer to that question :-)